# How to convert this big code to Java 8 lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Im just new in java lambda and i struggling to make this code in lambda form please can someone at least tell me how to do it in big codes like this one
or should i use streams to make it easier and thx.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class charFile {

public static void main(String args[]) {


    TreeMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
    File file = new File("new.txt");
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file, "utf-8");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for (Character c : chars) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                continue;
            } else if (hashMap.containsKey(c)) {
                hashMap.put(c, hashMap.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }


}
```

}

Comment: If your code **works fine** but you are asking for ways to improve it then your question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why do you need to convert this big code to a lamba expression? For what interface? Or do you want to transform this entire class in an interface somehow? How?

Comment: i just ask if i could to convert it to lambda but it seems to be hard or maybe i should use functional programming to make the code less and easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("new.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
        .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
        .filter(Character::isLetter)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Comment: thx, it seems that i should use streams with lambda i knew it from searching that they almost work with each other.

Comment: Yes, they strongly complement each other. You can technically use streams without lambdas, but it would probably be more clunky than your original loop.

Comment: You probably meant `Paths.get(file)`?

Comment: @Naman Oops... fixed.

Comment: Don’t forget to close the stream returned by `Files.lines()`. Also, the one-arg overload uses UTF-8 by default so you don’t need the second arg in this case.

Comment: @StuartMarks Interesting. I assumed it would use the system default.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing. The older APIs that have no charset arg use the default, which is system-specific, but which is _usually_ UTF-8. But on Windows it's often Windows-1252 and I've also sometimes seen it be ASCII. However, newer APIs (like `Files.lines`) that have no charset arg are specified to use UTF-8. This unfortunately means you have to read the docs carefully. No harm in being explicit though.